# How to save many records in one request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord

I have designed a form that looks like a spreadsheet.  A series of new records are created by entering data in fields in the last row of a table.  Since, I don't know what fields the user will choose to use (they can dictate what data pertains to them in preferences...and then only those input fields are visible in the form), the form needs to be dynamic.  Therefor, each input is a new record rather than all in the same db table row.  I opted to not user hstore in this case.

What is the best way, or even better...the rails way, of saving multiple records to a join model in one request?

Comment: I've decided to revisit hstore as a viable option...I think it is.  Any opinions?

Comment: Could be a good fit for MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this question appealing...look in to hstore.  It is very flexible...and definitely seems the way to solve these types of scenarios.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore